# About "gsheet" package in R

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, r-googlesheets

I have some questions about `gsheet` package, version 0.2.1. Here is my code in `shiny`.

```
urlA <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lVVGg2iRLtOaizrkaJHtPCyEnQiKAnJPyNj1kSSPXvY/edit?usp=sharing"
p_A <- gsheet2tbl(urlA)
```

Error message:

> ```
> Error in gsheet2text(url, format = "csv") : 
>   Unable to retrieve document. Is 'share by link' enabled for this sheet?
> ```

The URL is my google spreadsheet. I can not resolve this question. What can I do? There are no problem in the past.

Comment: Seems like a bug. As a workaround, you can just download it as a .csv file.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of this package and I just fixed this issue. Install the latest version from github:  

    devtools::install_github("maxconway/gsheet")  

The issue was generated because google changed their url format. 
Tell me if there's anything else not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of this package and I just fixed this issue. Install the latest version from github:

```
devtools::install_github("maxconway/gsheet")
```

This new version should be available on CRAN soon, as well.

The issue was generated because google changed their url format.
Tell me if there's anything else I can do to help.